# Execute PCI option rom, Network Controller on B:06/D:00/F:00 (motherboard Z10PE-D8-WS ACPI BIOS Revision 3101)

Tags: boot, bios, pci, asus

I have a motherboard Z10PE-D8-WS ACPI BIOS Revision 3101

which stuck at this screen

[image]

I have not added any news devices, just a night before shutdown the system using power button instead of "sudo shutdown -h now" from my Linux console.

Right now it stays in this state forever.

I can't get it BIOS settings etc.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you remove the NIC? Does it boot if you do remove it?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I have disconnected all connected devices (HDMI ports, USB ports etc) and then it has worked normally, hopefully will help someone in the future.